# How do I automatically execute `netctl start tq84-wifi` on bootup?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, startup, netctl

I have configured a wifi connection in `/etc/netctl/tq84-wifi` in a Arch Linux installation and am able to manually start it with `sudo netctl start tq84-wifi`.

Now I'd like to have my installation start the wifi connection automatically when I start Linux. I tried `sudo netctl-auto switch-to tq84-wifi`, yet this command tells me `Profile 'tq84-wifi' does not exist or is not available`.

So, what do I have to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute `sudo netctl enable tq84-wifi`. The [netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Profile_configuration) wiki page says:

---

#### Basic method

With this method, you can statically start only one profile per interface. First manually check that the profile can be started successfully with:

```
# netctl start profile
```

then it can be enabled using:

```
# netctl enable profile
```

This will create and enable a systemd service that will start when the computer boots. Changes to the profile file will not propagate to the service file automatically. After such changes, it is necessary to reenable the profile:

```
# netctl reenable profile
```

After enabling a profile, it will be started at next boot. Obviously this can only be successful, if the network cable for a wired connection is plugged in, or the wireless access point used in a profile is in range respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't quite understand what netctl-auto is. It uses wpa_actiond to automatically connect to ANY of the wireless profiles on an interface it's enabled on. For example:

```
$ sudo systemctl start netctl-auto@wlp2s0.service
```

If it's connected to the wrong network, then either use wifi-menu or the command you tried:

```
$ sudo netctl-auto switch-to correctNetwork
```

But if this is a computer that doesn't ever move, consider just `enable`ing the profile. `netctl-auto` uses extra memory (albeit not too much) but it also adds extra complexity. If you run:

```
$ sudo netctl enable tq84-wifi
```

then it will attempt to connect to `tq84-wifi` on boot and will not try anything else. You can also

```
$ sudo netctl start tq84-wifi
```

to attempt to connect immediately.

**TL;DR:** `netctl-auto` is for mobile computers such as laptops that should connect to and switch between any of multiple predefined networks automatically (this is what most OSes do by default). If the computer is not mobile, just `sudo netctl enable [profile]` to have it connect on boot.